# ListBox grouping and LINQ

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, listbox

Can I use LINQ for grouping in ListBox? 
I have property

```
public IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Rout>> GroupedTypeRouts
    {
        get { return Routs.GroupBy(x => x.Transport); }
    }
```

And I want show this in ListBox by groups.

Updated.
I've tried this

```
private CollectionViewSource groupedTypeRoutsView;
    public CollectionViewSource GroupedTypeRoutsView
    {
        get
        {
            if (groupedTypeRoutsView == null)
            {
                groupedTypeRoutsView = new CollectionViewSource();
                groupedTypeRoutsView.IsSourceGrouped = true;
                groupedTypeRoutsView.Source = GroupedTypeRouts;

            }

            return groupedTypeRoutsView;
        }
    }
public IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Rout>> GroupedTypeRouts
    {
        get { return Routs.GroupBy(x => x.Transport); }
    }
```

But I don't know how to show it in ListBox

```
 <ListView Grid.Row="2"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="9"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source=GroupedTypeRoutsView}">
                <ListView.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Image Source="{Binding Key, Converter={StaticResource TransportToImageConverter}}"></Image>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </ListView.GroupStyle>
            </ListView>
```

I get GroupedTypeRoutsView instead values and groups

Comment: This is not going to work out of the box. So the short answer is No. But the ListBox supports Grouping of ungrouped Data out of the box. You will find tutorials where this is solved ( http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/ ). I don't see any need for LINQ here.

Comment: remove the Source=..

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
    private ListCollectionView groupedTypeRoutsView;
    public ListCollectionView GroupedTypeRoutsView
    {
        get
        {
            if (groupedTypeRoutsView == null)
            {
                groupedTypeRoutsView = new ListCollectionView((IList)Routs);
                groupedTypeRoutsView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Transport"));
            }

            return groupedTypeRoutsView;
        }
    }


   <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedTypeRoutsView}" />
```